# Help understanding fixed effects interaction terms in nlme

Tags: lme4-nlme, nonlinear-regression

I am working through one of the nlraa vignettes (https://rdrr.io/cran/nlraa/f/vignettes/nlraa-Oddi-LFMC.Rmd) and am confused about the values used to test the interaction of fixed effects.
The authors give the following code to determine if the parameters of the beta growth function are affected by the fixed effects of crop, input, and their interaction:

```
fe <- fixef(fit2.me2) ## Some starting values with visual help
fit3.me2 <- update(fit2.me2, fixed = list(w.max + t.e + t.m ~ Crop),
                  start = c(fe[1], -10, 20, fe[2], -40, 0, fe[3], -40, 0))
## We next include the Input
fe2 <- fixef(fit3.me2)
fit4.me2 <- update(fit3.me2, fixed = list(w.max + t.e + t.m
                               ~ Crop + Input),
                  start = c(fe2[1:3], 0, fe2[4:6], 0, fe2[7:9], 0))
## and the interaction
fe3 <- fixef(fit4.me2)
fit5.me2 <- update(fit4.me2,
                   fixed = list(w.max + t.e + t.m
                     ~ Crop + Input + Crop:Input),
                  start = c(fe3[1:4], 0, 0,
                            fe3[5:8], 0, 0,
                            fe3[9:12], 0, 0))
```

Can someone clarify the `start = c(fe3[1:4],0,0 ....` in the interaction term? For example, if working with a dataset where factor A has 5 levels and factor B have 3 levels, how would the fixed effects interaction start be written?
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The first object 'fe' has the fixed effect parameter estimates, which for this nonlinear model are 'w.max', 't.e' and 't.m'. When you incorporate the effect of 'Crop' which has 3 levels, you include additional starting values for the differences for two of those crops compared to the reference. So the values '-10' and '20' are the initial values for the differences between the reference crop 'w.max' and the differences for each of the other two crops. In the last example, when the interaction is included you need additional zeros as starting values for the interaction term. The number of zeros is the product of the degrees of freedom for 'Crop' and 'Input' which is (3-1) * (2-1) = 2. 'Crop' and 'Input' enter this nonlinear model as linear predictors on the nonlinear parameters. Let me know if this is not clear enough.